# Change selected value if radio button is selected

Tags: jquery

I have a radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="suc" value="S">Suc
```

If I select radio button I disable lst2 as:

```
 $('input:radio[name="editList"]')
                       .click(function () {
                           if ($(this).val() === "S") {
                               $('#lst2').prop('disabled', true);
                           } else {
                                $('#lst2').prop('disabled', false);
                           }
                       });
```

But now I want know how can I change value of lst2 automatically with the same value of lst1 if radio button is selected, how can I do it into onChange state?

**Select JS:**

```
function getlst2(sender) {

  // sender: jQuery Object which called this method.
  sender.addClass("changed");
  $("#lst2").getJSONCatalog({
    url: 'https://demo9451608.mockable.io/getTest',
    valueProperty: "id",
    textProperty: "text"
  });
} 

$("#lst1").getJSONCatalog({
  url: 'https://demo9451608.mockable.io/getTest',
  valueProperty: "key",
  textProperty: "value",
  onChange: getlst2
});
```

Note: if radio is not selected you can choose lst2 value.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5wufz7yv/6/)

Comment: why not use a checkbox instead? there's no way to undo the radiobutton if it's selected already.  Ist2 will be disabled like forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('input:radio[name="editList"]').change(function (e) {
                           if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                               $('#lst2').prop('disabled', true); 
                             //set the value of lst1 to lst 2
                              $("#lst2").val($("#lst1").val());
                           } else {
                                $('#lst2').prop('disabled', true);
                           }
                           
                           
                       }); 
                       
                       $('#lst1').change(function (e) { 
                           if ($('input:radio[name="editList"]').is(':checked')) {
                               $('#lst2').prop('disabled', true); 
                             //set the value of lst1 to lst 2
                              $("#lst2").val($("#lst1").val());
                           } else {
                                $('#lst2').prop('disabled', true);
                           }
                           
                           
                       });
                       
                       (function($) {
  "use strict";

  $.fn.getJSONCatalog = function(options) {
   

    try {

      var self = this;

      var defaults = {
        url: null,
        headers: {},
        crossDomain: false,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        valueProperty: "",
        textProperty: "",
        dataExtended: null,
        selectedValue: null,
        assignWithoutProperties: false,
        appendDefaultFirstOption: true,
        defaultFirstOptionValue: "",
        defaultFirstOptionText: "-- Seleccione una Opción --",
        defaultFirstOptionDisabled: false,
        isChosenSelect: false,
        onChange: null,
        oneChange: null,
        onSuccess: function() {
          return false;
        },
        messageText: "Get JSON Catalog",
        list: null,
        devMode: false
      };

      var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);

      var appendOptions = function(optionsList) {

        var isChosenSelect = settings.isChosenSelect === true ? true : null;

        if (isChosenSelect) {
          self.chosen("destroy");
        }

        self.empty();

        if (settings.appendDefaultFirstOption === true) {
          self.append($("<option>", {
            value: settings.defaultFirstOptionValue,
            text: settings.defaultFirstOptionText,
            disabled: settings.defaultFirstOptionDisabled === false ? false : true
          }));
        }

        if (optionsList) {

          $.each(optionsList, function() {

            var optionObj;

            if (settings.assignWithoutProperties === false) {

              var hasProperties = {
                value: this[settings.valueProperty],
                text: this[settings.textProperty]
              };

              optionObj = hasProperties;

            } else if (settings.assignWithoutProperties === true) {

              var noProperties = {
                value: this,
                text: this
              };

              optionObj = noProperties;

            }

            if (optionObj) {

              var $option = $("<option>", optionObj);

              if (settings.dataExtended) {
                $option.attr("data-extended", this[settings.dataExtended]);
              }

              self.append($option);
            }

          });

          if (settings.selectedValue) {

            self.val(settings.selectedValue);

            $("option", self).filter(function() {
              return this.value === settings.selectedValue;
            }).prop("selected", true);

          }

          if (settings.onChange) {
            self.on("change", function() {
              settings.onChange(self);
            });
          }

          if (settings.oneChange) {
            self.one("change", function() {
              settings.oneChange(self);
            });
          }

        }

        if (isChosenSelect) {
          self.chosen({
            placeholder_text_single: "-- Seleccione una opción --",
            placeholder_text_multiple: "-- Seleccione múltiples opciones --",
            width: "100%"
          });
        }

      }

      var successfulResponse = function(data) {
        appendOptions(data);
        settings.onSuccess(data);
      };

      if (settings.url) {

        $.ajax({
          method: settings.method,
          dataType: settings.dataType,
          cache: false,
          url: settings.url,
          headers: settings.headers,
          crossDomain: settings.crossDomain,
          contentType: settings.contentType,
          beforeSend: function() {
            // Add hooks before sending data
          },
          success: function(data) {
            if (settings.devMode === true) console.log(data);
            successfulResponse(data);
          },
          failure: function(jqXhr) {
            //console.log("Estatus " + jqXhr.status + ". Error: " + jqXhr.statusText);
          },
          error: function(jqXhr) {
            //console.log("Estatus " + jqXhr.status + ". Error: " + jqXhr.statusText);
          },
          complete: function() {
            //Add complete hooks
          }
        });

      } else if (settings.list) {
        if (settings.devMode === true) console.log(settings.list);
        successfulResponse(settings.list);
      }

    } catch (e) {
      // console.log(e);
    }

    return undefined;
  }

}(jQuery));

                       
                

  // sender: jQuery Object which called this method.

  $("#lst2").getJSONCatalog({
    url: 'https://demo9451608.mockable.io/getTest',
    valueProperty: "id",
    textProperty: "value"
  });


$("#lst1").getJSONCatalog({
  url: 'https://demo9451608.mockable.io/getTest',
  valueProperty: "key",
  textProperty: "value",
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="suc" value="S">Suc

<select id="lst1"></select>
<select id="lst2"></select>
```

Comment: Its supposed if I click in`lst1` option "Valor 1" I will get "Valor 1" into `lst2` when radio button is clicked.

Comment: Sorry my bad used `list1` instead of `lst1` but you have values like 1 2 3 in select so it ll have that value

Comment: so you say we need same values into two select lists, youre correct so we can change textpropert of lst2 to "value" but it doesn´t change value of lst2 :(

Comment: exactly otherwise you need to append new `<option></option>` tag dynamically it may give you value problem because both would have same value

Comment: as you can see if you select one value of lst1 and then click on radio button it change it, but I want to do once radio is clicked then select value on lst1 to copy it to lst2

Comment: How do I change it when I change selected value with radio button active?

Comment: Yes, if you run your example it works now, but only when you select one value from lst1 and hen click on radio button. And I want to select first radio button then select value of lst1 and lst2 populate from that lst1

Comment: Again you need to handle event on select change, check the updated answer ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can use a checkbox "if in future the value need to be changed". A pure javascript solution as follows.

```
function handleClick(cb) {
if(cb.checked){
 document.getElementById('secondOption').disabled = true;
}
 else {
 document.getElementById('secondOption').disabled = false;
 document.getElementById('secondOption').value = "default";
}
}

 function check() {
   var checkBox = document.getElementById('secondOption').disabled;
   var selectedValue = document.getElementById('firstOption').value;
   var element = document.getElementById('secondOption');
       if(checkBox) {
element.value = selectedValue;
 }
}
```

A working plunker [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/jkZnrfVpmaFA0EQ3ElaH?p=preview)

Comment: I can´t use checkbox because I don´t have only one radio button, I just use one to give some example. I want exactly what you do but with radio button.

Comment: @Gerardo I've updated the plunker with radio button. Let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry, but maybe you could explain yourself better, it's kind of hard to understand you.*

**Kind of Answer**
The change event exists with jQuery, just use change(callbackFunction) function on a jQuery object. in the change callback function, "this" variable is the changed object.
Take care : With a radio button, the change event could be triggered multiple time, for each changing item, so the checked state is important.
Just get the value with val() function on jQuery object.